# Node.js - Store sockets in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a chat server with nodejs and mongo as a demo. I have it where each user can send another authenticated user a message. What I am trying to do now is make is scalable.

My Idea is to save the sockets inside MongoDB and then have several node servers running that check to see if that user is online in the DB, if so, send the message to that socket.

Although when I try to store the socket in the DB via `JSON.Stringify` into a `type:String`, it gives me an `error: 'Exception in cluster master process: Converting circular structure to JSON'`

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: It is not a good idea, since your `socket` is not actually a piece of Document or Data. Also, I don't see a way to store it inside MongoDB.

Comment: What would be the best solution to making it scalable?

Comment: Why not just use a popular protocol and server module, such as XMPP?

Comment: I was very brief about the summary of the project, but it will be going on a gaming site that gets millions of pageviews a day. It will be a little more complex than just a chat server, but I didnt want to flood the question with what the apps going to do, basically I cant seem to find a good solution to saving sockets globally for multiple servers to check.

Comment: qrpike, RedisStore is exactly for that purpose. Implementing it even caused a major rewrite for Socket.IO this year :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale you Socket.IO file, [Redis](http://redis.io/) is the way to do it, namely using [RedisStore](http://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/efcc7f096954e5a7/a2f5e74f026936ae?lnk=raot), check the following resources:

[How can I scale socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944714/how-can-i-scale-socket-io) 
https://github.com/dshaw/talks/tree/master/2011-10-jsclub 
http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/