# socket.io+redis+expressjs cluster - get socket object in expressjs request

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing

Question based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650183/4478897

I tried to find this solution but nothing seems to work in the way that I need.

Clustering `expressjs` and `socket.io` we can share sessions using redis and send `io` messages inside `io` world (`io.sockets.on('connection',`...). The problem is if we want to send the message (or use a simple `socket.join/leave`) inside the `expressjs` world (`route.get/post`).

If we are not using clusters we can atach the client `socket` object to the express `request` object (or simply `export` the `io` object) and then use it at any time on any GET/POST route.

At the other hand, if we are clustering and use the mentioned method to get the `socket` object inside the `expressjs` world, sometimes the `socket` object is undefined because the `socket` object for this client is initialized at other `worker`.

Some example flow:

- Client connects to http://localhost and `worker 1` handles this request.
- After the page is loaded, the client connects to `socket.io`. `Worker 2` handles this connection.
- Client do a POST and again `worker 1` or `worker X` handles this request.

In this case when the client do the POST, only the `worker 2` knows the `socket` object for this client. So this will get an undefined `socket` object.

So, the question:

How can we get the client `socket` object from any `worker` to reuse it on `expressjs request` object.

Maybe my code is wrong but is almost like the link to the answer mentioned above.

---

NOTEs

- Don't want to use some kind of proxy.
- Don't want to migrate to other libraries (expressio, sockjs...)
- Sorry for my English :)

*Using last nodejs, socket.io, expressjs, socket.io-redis, redis... versions*

Don't hesitate to ask something!

---

**UPDATE 1**

Possible solution but still need to test it. Dont know if this is a really good: solution.

- **UPDATE 3**: Working code on my own answer

**UPDATE 2**

Like update 1 but using https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well finally tried the code and it works (with some misspells modifications and other things) but i'm sure that needs to be a better code somewhere. So i'm open to more answers!

This code is part of my socket.io module when authorize the client socket and some other stuff...

```
  var redis = require("redis");
  var redisPub = redis.createClient();
  var redisSub = redis.createClient();
  var PubSubChannel = "clusterChannel";

  // Function that checks if this worker knows the socket object of this socketId.
  // If not, publish the message to all the other sockets (workers)
  io.socketDo = function (type, socketId, roomName) {
    if (typeof io.sockets.connected[socketId] != "undefined") {
      if (type === "join") {
        return io.sockets.connected[socketId].join(roomName);
      }
      if (type === "leave") {
        return io.sockets.connected[socketId].leave(roomName);
      }
    } else {
      redisPub.publish(
        PubSubChannel,
        JSON.stringify({
          type: type,
          socketId: '' + socketId,
          roomName: roomName
        })
      );
    }
  };

  // Subscribe to some channel
  redisSub.subscribe(PubSubChannel);

  // When this worker receive a message from channel "PubSubChannel" checks
  // if it have the socket object for this socketId and do the operation
  redisSub.on("message", function (channel, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var type = data.type;
    var socketId = data.socketId;
    var roomName = data.roomName;
    if ((type === "join" || type === "leave") && channel == PubSubChannel){
      if (typeof io.sockets.connected[socketId] != "undefined") {
        if (type === "join") {
          return io.sockets.connected[socketId].join(roomName);
        }
        if (type === "leave") {
          return io.sockets.connected[socketId].leave(roomName);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Then just simply export the module and attach it to your expressjs `request => req.io = io`

```
// req.session.socketId value is fetched on "io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {" 
// by express to socket.io using redis shared sessions
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.io.socketDo('join', req.session.socketId, 'someRoomToJoin');

    // IT WORKS!
    req.io.sockets.in('someRoomToJoin').emit('text'); 

    req.io.socketDo('leave', req.session.socketId, 'someRoomToLeave');
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`remoteJoin` and `remoteLeave` methods were added in socket.io-redis  `3.0.0`:

```
io.adapter.remoteJoin('<my-id>', 'room1', function (err) {
  if (err) { /* unknown id */ }
  // success
});

io.adapter.remoteLeave('<my-id>', 'room1', function (err) {
  if (err) { /* unknown id */ }
  // success
});
```

Note: The implementation looks a lot (hopefully?) like the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313377/socket-ioredisexpressjs-cluster-get-socket-object-in-expressjs-request/35614707#35614707).

Comment: i saw the merge. Thank you anyway :D