# use node.js cluster with socket.io chat application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to learn node.js cluster with socket.io to create a chat application... the problem is that I can't seem to get things working.

i've been trying to go through all the tutorials including the one that I get from this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310635/scaling-socket-io-to-multiple-node-js-processes-using-cluster/18650183#18650183`

when I try to open two browsers, the messages does not go to the other browser.

here's the code that i got

```js
var express = require('express'),
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    net = require('net'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    socket_redis = require('socket.io-redis');

var port = 3000,
    num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
    // them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
    // for example.
    var workers = [];

    // Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
    var spawn = function(i) {
        workers[i] = cluster.fork();

        // Optional: Restart worker on exit
        workers[i].on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('respawning worker', i);
            spawn(i);
        });
    };

    // Spawn workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        spawn(i);
    }

    // Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.
    // This is a hot path so it should be really fast. The way it works
    // is by converting the IP address to a number by removing non numeric
  // characters, then compressing it to the number of slots we have.
    //
    // Compared against "real" hashing (from the sticky-session code) and
    // "real" IP number conversion, this function is on par in terms of
    // worker index distribution only much faster.
    var worker_index = function(ip, len) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(ip[i])) {
                s += ip[i];
            }
        }

        return Number(s) % len;
    };

    // Create the outside facing server listening on our port.
    var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
        // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
        // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
        // it the connection.
        var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
        worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
    }).listen(port);
} else {
    // Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
    var app = new express();

    // Here you might use middleware, attach routes, etc.
    app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


    // Don't expose our internal server to the outside.
    var server = app.listen(),
        io = socketio(server);

    // Tell Socket.IO to use the redis adapter. By default, the redis
    // server is assumed to be on localhost:6379. You don't have to
    // specify them explicitly unless you want to change them.
    io.adapter(socket_redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

    // Here you might use Socket.IO middleware for authorization etc.

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('New client connection detected on process ' + process.pid);

        socket.emit('welcome', {message: 'Welcome to BlueFrog Chat Room'});
        socket.on('new.message', function(message) {
            socket.emit('new.message', message);
        })

    });


    // Listen to messages sent from the master. Ignore everything else.
    process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
        if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
            return;
        }

        // Emulate a connection event on the server by emitting the
        // event with the connection the master sent us.
        server.emit('connection', connection);

        connection.resume();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is not working? what have you tried? what's the problem?

Comment: the messages I send from a browser reaches my server and the message itself goes back to the same browser, but it does not get published to other browser... i think this has something to do with emitting i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that the messages from a client are not broadcasted to the other clients. you can solve this easily using :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('New client connection detected on process ' + process.pid);

    socket.emit('welcome', {message: 'Welcome to BlueFrog Chat Room'});
    socket.on('new.message', function(message) {
        socket.emit('new.message', message);  // this line sends the message back to the emitter
        socket.broadcast.emit('my message', msg); // this broadcasts the message to all the clients
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to emit a message. The one you're using emits the message only to the socket that first sent a 'new.message' message to the server. Which means that a socket will receive the message that you emit there only if it first sent a message 'new.message'. That's why, in your browser, the client originating the message is the only one receiving it back.

Change it to:

```
    socket.on('new.message', function(message) {
        io.sockets.emit('new.message', message);//use this if even the browser originating the message should be updated.
        socket.broadcast.emit('new.message', message);//use this if everyone  should be updated excpet the browser source of the message.
    })
```

Here are the different ways you can emit:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //This message is only sent to the client corresponding to this socket.
    socket.emit('private message', 'only you can see this');

    //This message is sent to every single socket connected in this 
    //session, including this very socket.
    io.sockets.emit('public message', 'everyone sees this');

    //This message is sent to every single connected socket, except
    //this very one (the one requesting the message to be broadcasted).
    socket.broadcast.emit('exclude sender', 'one client wanted all of you to see this');
});
```

You can also add sockets to different rooms when they connect so that you only communicate messages with sockets from a given room:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //Add this socket to a room called 'room 1'.
    socket.join('room 1');

    //This message is received by every socket that has joined 
    //'room 1', including this one. (Note that a socket doesn't
    //necessarily need to belong to a certain room to be able to
    //request messages to be sent to that room).
    io.to('room 1').emit('room message', 'everyone in room 1 sees this');

    //This message is received by every socket that has joined 
    //'room 1', except this one.
    socket.broadcast.to('room 1').emit('room message', 'everyone in room 1 sees this');
});
```