# Socket.io/node.js how much emits can handle per 1 second

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I wanna know if anyone <3 how much socket.io/node.js a single server can handle emits per second?

The (on emit) in the server-side has, Let's say 1 query to MySQL which is SELECT *

How much it could handle? let's say CPU mm 1v core and ram lets say 3 GB or you can say any example you've tried any opinions? (per 1 second)
And what best practice to do for high emits? any answers guys <3

(Just an average or expectation will do)

Comment: Question similar to this is already answered before, please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47285724/12639279

Comment: Thank you so much! but the MySQL query part in my question is so important any thoughts about it too?