# Socket.io issue handling session issues with HA middleware

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Current setup:
Node.js - 8.3.4
Socket.io - 2.0.4
Express - 4.15.4

I have recently run into an issue with running 2 concurrent instances of a middleware service that allows for socket.io connections. For traffic routing our company uses a combination of F5 and treafik, and I have been told that there is no way to guarantee a connection with the same server upon a new request. So when the front end connects to the middleware the first time, I get data from the socket connection. However, one refresh will likely cause several Session ID errors related to socket.io. This is because I am most likely being directed to the other server. I have been looking for a solution for this for a couple hours and this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session seems like a good possibility.

I feel like this is something that a lot of people have had to deal with. Can anyone give me their thoughts on what they have done to solve this issue? We currently use a Redis server to store user session data (auth related), I was thinking we could use it to store the Session IDs from socket.io then change the socket connection process to see if a session ID exists.

Thank you,
Ryan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaling Socket.IO to multiple Node.js processes using cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310635/scaling-socket-io-to-multiple-node-js-processes-using-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) module?

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run
>   multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that
>   can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.
>
> If you need to emit events to socket.io instances from a non-socket.io
>   process, you should use [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter).

Also this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650183/7526159